# Jquery Select2 V4 in Ajax mode not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-9, jquery-select2-4

Using Select2 4.0 in my forms' select elements, those intented to be filled dynamically in Ajax mode are not working in IE9. It displays an empty select with no placeholder.

The ones in classic mode (pre-filled select lists) are displaying and working (select2 search..) correctly.

Using the older version 3.5.2 in other pages, the problem doesn't occur...!

Is this a known issue? Fixable one?

Thx

Here's the JS:

```
$(".select2Ajax").not(".select2-container").each(function(){
        var min = $(this).data('min'); // 3

        var configs = {
            "width":"100%",
            language: $locale, // 'fr'

            ajax: {

                    dataType: 'json',
                    delay: 250,
                    data: function (params) {
                        return {
                            q: params.term
                        };
                    },
                    processResults: function (data, page) {
                        return {
                            results: data
                        };
                    },
                    cache: true
                },
            escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, 
            minimumInputLength: min

        };
        $(this).select2(configs);
    })//.each
```

The HTML:

```
<select id="contrat_kam" name="contrat[kam]" class="select2Ajax form-control" data-min="3" data-ajax--url="/My/Ajax/Source/url-returning-json-formatted-list/from-search-term">
    <option value="">Here is my intitial placeholder</option>
</select>
```

And an example of what's returned form the server when typing into the select2 field, in a normal client (Chrome):

```
[{"id":"75484567","text":"Bestnameever Ronald"},{"id":"12344568","text":"Nameofdude C\u00e9dric"},{"id":"01202795","text":"SecondDudesName John"},{"id":"00709297","text":"Doe John"}]
```

Thank you

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: No there wasn't. In fact it was not a JS or IE error: I'm on Symfony2, and the problem happened after the form submit. The select which was causing trouble was regenerated without the correct params & classes :/

Comment: So I solved the issue..

Comment: You might want to post an answer explaining what the issue what, just in case someone else runs into it.

Comment: ha ok I was deleting it because I was wrong on the origin of the problem. It was in fact a Symfony knowledge issue.. Does it make sense to answer it here?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved my problem, but it wasn't a JS/IE problem.

I am working under Symfony 2. The problem appeared after the form submit. Having a validation error, Symfony displays the form page again with the errors on the fields.

I was using Select2 in AJAX mode because the choices list was way too heavy to handle, nearly causing the browser to crash with more than 7000 options to display..
So I created the select (sf2 entity choice list) with an empty array for choices list.

BUT 
If you try to save your form with the new value, which was NOT in the (empty) original choice list, SF doesn't validate it, and throws a validation error.

SO
you have to add a form PRE_SUBMIT event listener, to add the select with your selected value in it, to your formType.
Which is complete other subject :)

The problem was that the new select that I defined in the form event listener did'nt have the correct parameters (class, data attributes..), preventing the select2 to work.

My bad!

So the subject would rather find his place in a Symfony 2 thread..